# What is the efficacy of Pertussis booster vaccine among different age groups?

Tags: vaccination

The Murray Microbiology book says that it is prefentially 10 years, similarly Estonian and Finnish health associations.

However, my professor says that it can be 5-7 years.

I started to think if the age is affecting here to the result.

**When should you take booster vaccination of Pertussis if you are**
a) 25 years old,
b) 50 years old,
c) 70 years old, and
d) 90 years old?

My professor says that there is no significant studies about the efficacy of Pertussis booster vaccination among different age groups.
**Is this true?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not true, see references 1 and 2 for this purpose. From these articles which followed up booster vaccinations for pertussis it seems that there is at least some protection 5 and 8 years after the boost.

There is another study, which says that 10 years are relatively safe to assume, as the reduction in antibody levels over time estimated from the 5 year study would still allow protective levels of antibodies. See reference 3 for details.

One of the problems to make statements about the duration of the protection is the lack of data. Additionally there was a change in the vaccine from whole cell (which is pretty immungenic, but has higher number unwanted side effects) against a acellular vaccine. This change happened in the 90s, so there are no longterm data available. See reference four for more details.

The common recommendation at the moment for adults is to repeat the booster vaccination every 10 years (together with tetanus and diphteria) and for people which have close contact to unvaccinated persons every 5 years to prevent infections (see reference 4).

References:

1. [Immunity to pertussis 5 years after booster immunization during
   adolescence.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17443462)
2. [Immune responses to pertussis antigens eight years after booster
   immunization with acellular vaccines in adults.](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3832/wwdif25k_pdf.htm)
3. [How long can we expect pertussis protection to last after the
   adolescent booster dose of tetanus-diphtheria-pertussis (Tdap)
   vaccines?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2532581/)
4. [Acellular pertussis vaccine use in risk groups (adolescents,
   pregnant women, newborns and health care workers): A review of
   evidences and recommendations](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3832/48fgi993_pdf.htm)